# How to instruct std::unordered_map's value construction for objects that don't have a default constructor

Tags: c++11, unordered-map

Suppose I have the following class:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int bar) : bar(bar) {}

    int bar;
}
```

How can I instruct a `std::unordered_map<int, Foo> map` to construct `Foo(100)` whenever they are needed, eg:

- map initialization
- map operator []

In order for the following snippet to work:

```
std::unordered_map<int, Foo> map;

assertTrue(map[11223344].bar == 100);
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: `std::unordered_map<int, Foo> map;` should work; do you have issues with it? `operator[]` is not going to work; just avoid it.

Comment: Add default constructor to Foo

Answer (score 0):

When `Foo` doesn't have a default constructor, using `std::unordered_map::operator[]` cannot work. But everything that doesn't require default construction of Foo will work, e.g. initialization:

```
std::unordered_map<int, Foo> map {
   {10, Foo{42}},
   {20, Foo{43}}
};
```

as well as in-place construction of new entry:

```
map.emplace(11223344, 100);
```